# Haskell recursive find function and Data.Foldable find explanation

Tags: haskell, find

given (No homework):

```
first' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
-- Finds the first element of a list that satisfies a given condition.
```

1. I got lost after this statement: 
   `if p x then Just x else Nothing)`
   How do I continue to make it recursive?
2. I found this:

   ```
   -- | The 'find' function takes a predicate and a structure and returns
   -- the leftmost element of the structure matching the predicate, or
   -- 'Nothing' if there is no such element.
   find :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Maybe a
   find p = getFirst . foldMap (\ x -> First (if p x then Just x else Nothing))
   ```

But I do not understand this section: `getFirst . foldMap (\ x -> First (`

Can someone explain this statement?

Answer (score 2):

If you are learning Haskell, I'd recommend you forget about `Foldable` and `First` for now, since these involve more advanced topics than needed to implement your `first'`.

As a hint, try to work out a simple recursive definition like the following:

```
-- Finds the first element of a list that satisfies a given condition.
first' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
first' p [] = ...
first' p (x:xs) = ...
   where
   -- the first in the tail xs
   rec = first' p xs
```

Think about it:

- what should be the first satisfying `p` in the empty list?
- assuming `rec` is the first satisfying `p` in the tail list `xs`, how would you express the first satisfying `p` in the full list `x:xs`? You can use an if-then-else for that.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, but I still have my original question:
In "normal" recursive function, I iterarate as long as a condition is not satisfied (result = Nothing), or if the condition is satisfied, (result = Just x) we stop.
Here I need three conditions: Nothing, Just x, continue iterating.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, but I still have my original question:
It is the Maybe statement that confuses me.

In "normal" recursive function, I iterate as long as a condition is not satisfied (result = Nothing), or if the condition is satisfied, (result = Just x) we stop.

Here I need three conditions: Nothing, Just x and  continue iterating.

How can I overcome this difficulty?

Comment: @Atir If the list is empty, you know there's no value satisfying `p`, so you can return `Nothing`. Otherwise, you can check `p x`: it that holds, you can return `Just x`, otherwise, you recurse with the rest of the list.

Answer (score 2):

> But I do not understand this section: getFirst . foldMap (\ x -> First (

First, let's look a bit at `First`, e.g., in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids). It is a *monoid*, defined like this:

```
newtype First a = First { getFirst :: Maybe a }  
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

and

```
instance Monoid (First a) where  
    mempty = First Nothing  
    First (Just x) `mappend` _ = First (Just x)  
    First Nothing `mappend` x = x
```

Intuitively, this means the following:

- The "empty" element is a `First` of `Nothing`
- "appending" two elements is a `First` of the first `Just` of them if there is one, else `First Nothing`.

So, as its name implies, it is a monoid which "records" the first `Just` it encountered.

---

If you look at [`foldMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html), it, unsurprisingly, performs a combination of folding a mapped version of everything in the foldable. Intuitively, then, if the foldable contained some `Just`, then the result of `foldMap` is the `First` such `Just`; otherwise, it is `First Nothing`.

---

Now, you want to extract the value from this `First` into a `Maybe`. This is what `getFirst` does.

The overall line composes `getFirst` with `foldMap`.